# Natural Language Processing - Similar to ngram

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I'm currently working on a NLP project that is trying to differentiate between synonyms (received from Python's NLTK with WordNet) in a context.  I've looked into a good deal of NLP concepts trying to find exactly what I want, and the closest thing I've found is n-grams, but its not quite a perfect fit.

Suppose I am trying to find the proper definition of the verb "box".  "Box" could mean "fight" or "package"; however, somewhere else in the text, the word "ring" or "fighter" appears.  As I understand it, an n-gram would be "box fighter" or "box ring", which is rather ridiculous as a phrase, and not likely to appear.  But on a concept map, the "box" action might be linked with a "ring", since they are conceptually related.

Is n-gram what I want? Is there another name for this? Any help on where to look for retrieving such relational data?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word sense disambiguation in NLTK Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699810/word-sense-disambiguation-in-nltk-python)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into `word sense disambiguation (WSD)`, it is the problem of determining which "sense" (meaning) of a word is activated by the use of the word in a particular context, a process which appears to be largely unconscious in people.