# How to determine contextually relevant synonyms?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, nlp

I'm new to NLP, so this might seem very basic.

How can I determine the best synonyms for a word based on the context of the sentence or paragraph it is in?

Is there an API or library that does this automatically? Something that takes a word and a paragraph and returns contextually relevant synonyms based on that paragraph.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called [word sense disambiguation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-sense_disambiguation). There are many methods, and I'm not an expert in them, but one pythonic option with NLTK is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699810/word-sense-disambiguation-in-nltk-python)