# How to get correct synsets from the raw text?

Tags: nltk, wordnet, lemmatization, pos-tagger

I need to create a table, containing relations between words (synsets) from any raw text using path_similarity method.

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> sent = "I went to the bank to deposit money".split()
>>> wn.synsets('bank')
[Synset('bank.n.01'), Synset('depository_financial_institution.n.01'), Synset('bank.n.03'), Synset('bank.n.04'), Synset('bank.n.05'), Synset('bank.n.06'), Synset('bank.n.07'), Synset('savings_bank.n.02'), Synset('bank.n.09'), Synset('bank.n.10'), Synset('bank.v.01'), Synset('bank.v.02'), Synset('bank.v.03'), Synset('bank.v.04'), Synset('bank.v.05'), Synset('deposit.v.02'), Synset('bank.v.07'), Synset('trust.v.01')]
```

**How can I get the correct synset for each word from the raw text?**

I can get the lemmas and POS tags as such:

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> wnl.lemmatize('banks')
u'bank'
>>> pos_tag(['banks'])
[('banks', 'NNS')]
```

**But how do I get the correct synset/sense number?**

Comment: are you looking for a word sense disambiguation software? Have you tried `nltk.wsd.lesk`? https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/wsd.py

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's the solution I've been looking for.

Comment: see also: https://github.com/alvations/pywsd (Disclaimer: I wrote them)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word sense disambiguation in NLTK Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699810/word-sense-disambiguation-in-nltk-python)